# Next.js server component data refresh when it changed in background service. App router

Tags: next.js, app-router, react-server-components, next.js14

I have Next.js 14 app with app router.

Structure:

```
app
    ...
    example
        page.tsx // only wrapping
    ...
    layout.tsx // root layout (no data)
    page.tsx // root page (no data)
    ...
components
    Table.tsx (load and display data)
...
background-services
    exmpl.bg-service.ts // makes external api requests and save data to db via prisma
...
stores
    exmpl.store.ts // class with wrapping prisma funcs
                   // funcs: async add(value), getPage(page, limit)
```

I need to refresh data in `Table.tsx` when my `exmpl.bg-service.ts` saved new data into db.

I wanted call `revalidatePath(...)` (with any props inside) from `exmpl.bg-service.ts`, after insert data.
And after and also after a little timeout.

I tried create server action, that call `revalidatePath(...)`.

```js
// action
'use server';

export const refresh = async (formData: FormData) => {
  revalidatePath(...);
};


// exmpl.bg-service.ts
await store.add(...);

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('test', 'test');

await refresh(formData);
```

I tried the following:

```js
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

```js
export const runtime = 'edge'
export const revalidate = 0; // and export const revalidate = N sec
```

```js
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache';
 
export default async function Table() {
  noStore();
  const result = await store.getPage(...);
  ...
}
```

I also tried applying `noStore();` to functions into `exmpl.bg-service.ts`.

And I also tried calling `prisma` directly from the `Table.tsx`

```js
// noStore() is also what I used here 
const data = await prisma.exmplTable.findMany({...});

return (
    <table>
    // ...
    </table>
);
```

I only achieved success by making periodic calls to `server actions` from the child client component. But I don't like this option and it is not very suitable for me, because data and `exmpl.bg-service.ts` can be received with different intervals.

And, of course, I tried getting the data directly into `page.tsx`.